# Angular 2 - Service in Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two `services` I want to use in my Angular2 application. When I try to use `GuideService` in `GlobalsService` and `GlobalsService` in `GuideService` I get this error:

`zone.js:392
 Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for GuideService: (?, ?).
    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GuideService: (?, ?).
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata`

My services :

```
export class GlobalsService {

     [...]

     constructor(private guideService: GuideService) { }

     [...]

}

export class GuideService {

     [...]

     constructor(private globals: GlobalsService) { }

     [...]

 }
```

Is there an other way to use the services in this way?

**EDIT**
I have this `GlobalsModule` which is imported in my `AppModule`:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {GlobalsService} from './globals.service'

@NgModule({
    providers: [GlobalsService],
    imports: [CommonModule]
})

export class GlobalsModule {
}
```

Comment: Is `GlobalsService ` declared in your module?

Comment: Do I have to declare it in my `GuideModule` or in my `AppModule`? If I have to declared it, can I access it the same way I do it now or do I have to use it in a different way?

Comment: Actually, before the declare, is it provided (i.e. included in your `providers` meta data)?

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would disapprove of such a circular dependency, and perhaps this should be handled by a third service which injects both services. Anyways, I do think what you are trying to do is possible using `@Inject` with `forwardRef`, both present in the `"@angular/core"` package:

```
export class GlobalsService {

     [...]

     constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => GuideService))
        private guideService: GuideService
     ) {}

     [...]

}

export class GuideService {

     [...]

     constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => GlobalsService))
        private globals: GlobalsService
     ) {}

     [...]

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still get an error, but I will use a third service to handle this.

Comment: I have forgotten about `forwardRef`. This answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Angular will not be able to construct any of your services. Services cannot depend on each other in constructor dependency injection.

Behind the scenes, Angular creates lists of services and sorts the list based on services needed to construct other services (services without dependencies goes first). In this case, `service1` depends on `service2` and `service2` depends on `service1`.

Workaround:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalsService {

     [...]

     constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

     [...]


    get guideService() {
        return this.injector.get(GuideService);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class GuideService {

     [...]

     constructor(private globals: GlobalsService) { }

     [...]

}
```

Note: Circural dependency in most cases means that your design is wrong. Each service should have clear responsibility and such design makes it hard to see. In such situations you should consider to put the code in one service.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still get an error, but I will use a third service to handle this.